# How to see console log without remote debugging using react native on android? (genymotion)

Tags: android, react-native

I have a peculiar problem. My hardware is old and slow, so when I try to use genymotion with remote debugging, it's so slow it's unusable (I mean *wait-10-minutes-for-simple-action* unusable).

Running on device has its own set of problems which I won't go into here so it's out of question too.

So how do I see console logs without remote debugging? It's also okay for me to use a workaround like yellow/red screens, but I don't know how to display those.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use terminal for (Android) debugging.

```
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

or you can use Android Studio for debugging. For iOS you can use Xcode.

**Updated**

You can display logs Android or iOS by following commands in a terminal:

```
react-native log-ios
react-native log-android
```

Checkout the [Debugging](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging#accessing-console-logs) docs for more detail.

Comment: How about for iOS?

Comment: `react-native log-ios`

Comment: Thanks Pir, however this only works if run in simulator. The `adb` technique works even when run on device. I was wondering if there was similar for when running on iOS device.